# Check value for containing String

Tags: ruby

I want to raise error if I have these two conditions:

```
command_options[:gateways] == %w(staging_bank) && command_options[:env] == %w(all)
```

I tried this:

```
raise "Testing All gateways is not allowed in staging_bank." unless command_options[:gateways] == %w(staging_bank) && command_options[:env] == %w(all)
```

But I get error `[]': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)

What is the proper way to implement this?

Comment: Can you describe what you want this function to do?

Comment: You write that you "want to raise [an] error **if** ... these two conditions [are met]." Why are you using **`unless`** instead? It's totally opposite.

Comment: Issue is not clear. What is `command_options`?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way would be to compare comparable types. From the naming it looks like `command_options[:env]` is meant to be a single string. And you're comparing it to an array, `%w(all)`. This won't work, naturally (the comparison will be always false). Make up your mind and compare apples with apples.

As for the actual error message, it's unrelated to the comparisons. Looks like `command_options` is an array and not a hash (as you probably meant it to be).

Also read up on `Array#include?`, this is what you'll need, I think.